# Buenas prácticas en Variables PHPOO

Tags: php, mvc, variables

Estoy trabajando con MVC y me surgen dudas con este tema dentro de la clase.

¿En que caso debería marcar una variable como `public`, `protected` o `private` y en que casos bastaría una local?

No pregunto la diferencia entre ellas, esto lo se, dudo en que casos es mejor por ejemplo marcar una variable como public y luego acceder a ella mediante `$this` o en que casos bastaría con usar una local: `$data`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No estoy seguro si esta pregunta se base en opiniones o no, sin embargo una variable se define como `public $variable` / `private $variable` / `protected $variable` cuando se va a utilizar en varios métodos de la clase.

```
class miClase 
{
    public $variable;

    public function metodo1()
    {
        // hacer algo con $this->variable
    }

    public function metodo2()
    {
        // hacer algo con $this->variable
    }

}
```

En caso que solo se utilice en un método, puede ser más conveniente definirla/utilizarla en dicho contexto únicamente.

```
public function metodo1()
{
    // utilizar $variable
}
```

---

En cuanto al tema de si la variable debe ser `public`, `protected` o `private`, ya depende del diseño de tu aplicación, según los patrones de diseño, SOLID, entre otras prácticas.

Comment: una variable `private` no la puedes usar en varios métodos de la misma clase?

Comment: mira la edición que hice, ya sabía que vendrían ese tipo de preguntas.

Comment: me refiero a lo que dices: `una variable se define como public $variable cuando se va a utilizar en varios métodos de la clase`...

Comment: Lo sé, es cuestión de interpretar el concepto/contexto, comparando con el ejemplo que da el OP al final.

Answer (score 1):

En mi opinion debes poner todas las variables `private` o `protected` y poner solo los métodos (Getter/Setters) `public`, al menos que tengas una buena razón para poner las variables `public`.

Answer (score 0):

A ver. Dentro de una clase las variables de clase, o "propiedades" son visible para todos los demás métodos.

Una variable que declaras en un método es efímera. Dura mientras la usa el método.

En otras palabras, para que los métodos de una clase se puedan pasar información entre sí, la manera más razónable es usando el estado de una variable.

Ponerle private o protected a una variable es sano cuando no quieres que un tercero le meta mano a tu clase. Por último, a variables delicadas le haces métodos setter y getter.

la gracia de las variables protected es que sólo pueden ser inspeccionadas por clases hijas. El típico caso es cuando tienenes una familia de controllers o entities que heredan de la misma clase, y es muy elegante dejar tus clases cerradas para el resto del código. Por ejemplo publicas tu librería en Packagist pero sabes que es un componente que se instala y no interactúa con el resto del código. Tiene dos otres métodos públicos y representan exactamente el uso que tú querías ofrecer a los usuarios.

Si alguien se las arregló para romper un método protected y te deja un issue en Github, ya sabes que puedes mandarlo a buena parte.

Answer (score 0):

A ver primero que todo te recomiendo leer esta sección de la documentación [php_docs](http://php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.visibility.php)

Los tres atributos que mencionas son la visibilidad que tu como programador le das a los elementos de una determinada clase en php indican lo siguiente:

- **public** el atributo, método o clase son públicos y pueden ser accedidos por cualquier elemento que instancie un objeto de la clase, o utilice un elemento estático de la misma.
- **private** los elementos "privados" solo son accesibles dentro del alcance de la clase ( es accesible desde cualquier método que este descrito dentro de la clase [*para aclarar comentarios anteriores*]) y no pueden ser reverenciados  ni utilizados directamente fuera de la clase dueña del atributo.
- **protected** Los elementos son accesibles desde las clases que extiendan la clase dueña.

> Clase base para un Campeon de un juego. de ilustración

```
abstract class Campeon
{
    #nombre del campeon
    public $nombre;

    #modelo 3d para renderizado en el juego.
    protected $model;

    #arreglo de los objetos tipo skils que puede usar el campeon.
    protected $skills;

    /*
     * Este objeto imaginario seria el encargado de realizar la renderización
     */
    private $render_motor_object;

    /* Función imaginaria de renderizado. esta función recibe el modelo y los 
    skills de un determinado personaje y ejecuta el proceso de renderizado.
    */
    public function renderizar(){
        $this->render_motor_object->mostrar($this->model, $this->skills)
        # ....
        # ....  INTERCEPCIÓN 1
        # procesos complejos de renderizado.
        # por alguna extraña razon se necesita el modelo otra vez
        $this->render_motor_object->mostrar_particulas($this->model)
        # ....
        # ....
        # mas procesos 
    }
}
```

> Ahora viene la parte de explicar los distintos conceptos si nos
>   imaginamos que estamos creando un juego y creamos una clase para
>   representar a un campeón.

```
class Shaco extends Campeon
{

    function __construct($modelo_de_shaco)
    {
        $this->nombre = 'Shaco';

        # si podemos cambiar el modelo porque fue declarado protegido.
        # y exta clase al extender de Campeon tiene acceso.
        $this->model = $modelo_de_shaco;

        $this->skills = [];


    }
}
```

> Ahora en alguna parte del sistema, nosotros o otros programadores
>   desean utilizar esas clases, allí inicia a importar la forma que
>   declaramos los atributos.

lo primero es el uso de clases abstractas y lo que indica que es una clase base pero que no puede ser instanciada. solo puede ser extendida por lo que la siguiente linea es un error

```
$anri = new Campeon(); # ERROR LA CLASE CAMPEON ES ABSTRACTA.
```

Ahora tengo quiero crear una instancia de Shaco por que lo voy a incluir en una partida

```
    $shaco = new Shaco();
    $shaco->nombre = 'volibear';
```

> debido a que el atributo nombre es publico en la clase Campeón, este
>   puede ser modificado en cualquier parte como hice anteriormente lo que
>   causaría  que al el juego muestre el campeón shaco que he creado, pero
>   salga otro nombre, lo que no es un comportamiento NO deseado por lo
>   que en ese caso lo mejor es ser declararlo **protected**.

Es por la razón anterior que el atributo **model** si se declaro **protegido** por que yo como programador de la clase no quería que el modelo fuera cambiado  por clases externas de forma descontrolada, por que también podrían hacer cosas como la siguiente

`$shaco->model = new Modelo('volibear'); #ERROR EL ATRIBUTO MODELO ESPROTEGIDO`.

Debido a que el proceso de renderizado en la clase Campeon digamos que es muy importante, vemos que se declaro el render_motor_object privado, esto es para proteger el comportamiento del método renderizar(), para explicar esto imaginemos que el render_motor_object es publico, entonces yo podría hacer cosas como esto:

```
$shaco->render_motor_object = '';
```

I si esto pasa, claramente el método renderizar lanzara una excepción-
por lo que nosotros al crear nuestra clase campeón determinamos que **es un 
atributo muy importante y no debería ser cambiado inesperadamente.por lo que lo declaramos privado**